# How to put multiple products into one product with woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have a studio reservation system, there are three different studio types. We  provide three kinds of photographic equipment rental packages, and three kinds of food packages. I'd like them all to be on one product page with the ability for each "package" to have images and text. Can I do this in woocommerce ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for what woocommerce calls a "variable product". You can setup any number of attributes for variations each with unique pictures, pricing, etc.

More information here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

You can create a studio variable product, and create attributes such as: "food package" and "photographic equipment".